# How to display a layouts created in GroupLayout by CardLayout

Tags: java

I want to show a two layouts created in JFrame Form, so they are created in GroupManager (these layouts are in void method). I want to use CardLayout to change by button a 'main' layout to other layout.
Code below:

```
private JPanel loginCard, adminCard, userCard;
private final JPanel cards;
private final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

public Main() throws HeadlessException {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);


    cards = new JPanel();
    cards.setLayout(cl);
    cards.add(loginCard, "1");
    cards.add(adminCard, "2");

    cl.show(cards, "1");
}
public void loginCardLayout(){
loginCard = new JPanel();
    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(loginCard);
    loginCard.setLayout(layout);
loginButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            loginButtonHandler(e);
        }
    });
}
public void adminCardLayout(){
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout1 = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(adminCard);
    adminCard.setLayout(layout1);
}

private void loginButtonHandler(ActionEvent e){  
        cl.show(cards, "2");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Main();   
        }
    });
}
```

So, when I want run a project, console shows an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:997)
at Main.<init>(Main.java:55)
at Main$2.run(Main.java:296)
// and others errors at java.desktop/java.awt ....
```

I don't have idea to resolve my trouble. Please help me.

Comment: The layout manager used on a panel is irrelevant when adding components to a panel using a CardLayout. All the CardLayout does is manage which component is visible at any time. I would suggest you forget about using a GroupLayout. It is overly complicated and generally only used by an IDE. In any case you can read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for a working example that uses a `CardLayout`. Start with the working example and customize it for your requirement.

Comment: If you want to know why you get the NPE, then read the stack trace. It is telling you the problem is on link 55 of your class. You have a null variable. So figure out which variable is null and fix the problem.

Comment: @camickr I've repaired NPE, but still I have a trouble with add these GroupLayout to CardLayout. I've created a simple example using CardLayout and **JPanels**. It works. The trouble is add a GroupLayout to CardLayout. I don't know how to do it. Try cast a JPanel on GroupLayout, but it's wrong - netbeans said.

Comment: You don't add a GroupLayout to a CardLayout. You add a panel to a panel. So you have a parent panel that uses a CardLayout. Then you add 2 or more child panels to the parent panel. The layout managers used on the child panels are irrelevant. I have already suggested you don't use the IDE to generate your GUI code. The code generated is not maintainable and you spend more time learning the IDE instead of learning Swing and Java.

Comment: @camickr so, how to add GroupLayout to CardLayout when I must add a Container to creating a new GroupLayout?

Comment: I give up. The CardLayout has absolutely nothing to do with the GroupLayout.  You create a JPanel that uses a GroupLayout. You then add the "panel" to the panel that uses the CardLayout. The panel is just a component. The CardLayout only cares about the panel, not the layout manager used by the panel. I have never used the GroupLayout (for reasons given above). You have been given a link to the tutorial on how to use GroupLayout. If you insist on using the GroupLayout, then start with the demo code and make changes. I can't tell you what you are doing wrong. Learn from the working example.

Comment: @camickr okay, thanks for answer, so it's just impossible to use grouplayout and cardlayout right? heh :D. I'm going to change a this sh*t grouplayout to something other. Again thanks :)))

Comment: You still don't understand the concept. A layout manager is only used on an individual panel. So yes, one panel can use a CardLayout and another panel can use a GroupLayout.